# Java: How to return different Object/datatype based on value

Tags: java

Java: Need to return multiple objects based on given value.

`NewClass tes = new NewClass();`

`Object[][] obj ={{}};`

Example: If the browser is chrome return TestClass and if its IE browser return Obj

```
public <T extends Object> T getValue(String browser){

switch(browser):
case "Chrome": return tes;
case "IE": return obj;

}
```

In Java, is it possible return different object types in single method.

Note: Need to do for 50 methods so trying to find option to return object based on given browser type.

Comment: In Java, you can only return an object with a particular type.  So the only way to kinda return multiple types is if all the types you want to return are subclasses of the defined return type of the method in question.  Of course, `Object` is the one type that would allow you to return just about anything, but it says pretty much nothing about what's being returned. But maybe that's OK.  You're going to have to test for each possible type anyway, so just return an Object and then use `instanceof` to do your testing for the various return possibilities.

Comment: Just noticed your use of a generic type in your example.  That won't work.  That would only work if you want to have a series of methods, each of which returned just one type of object.  Here, you want to return different types from the same method.  Generics won't help you with that.  Have your `getValue` method just return an Object.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you have a look at the Factory design pattern. You will create objects without exposing the creation logic.

This is my interpretation. I do not know if it is what you want to implement.

```java
public enum BrowserType {
    CHROME, SAFARI, IE
}

//Browser is the parent class of all browser instances and it will also contain the common logic applicable for creating all types
public abstract class Browser {

    public Browser(BrowserType model) {
        this.model = model;
        arrangeParts();
    }

    private void arrangeParts() {
        // Do one-time processing here
    }

    // Do subclass level processing in this method
    protected abstract void construct();

    private BrowserType model = null;

    public BrowserType getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(BrowserType model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}

//    Safari is a concrete implementation of Browser type SAFARI
public class Safari extends Browser {

    Safari() {
        super(BrowserType.SAFARI);
        construct();
    }

    @Override
    protected void construct() {
        System.out.println("SAFARI BROWSER LOADED");
        // add accessories
    }
}

//    IE is concrete implementation of Browser type IE
public class IE extends Browser {

    IE() {
        super(BrowserType.IE);
        construct();
    }

    @Override
    protected void construct() {
        System.out.println("IE BROWSER LOADED");
        // add accessories
    }
}

//BrowserFactory.java is our main class implemented using factory pattern. It instantiates a browser instance only after determining its type.
public class BrowserFactory {
    public static Browser buildBrowser(BrowserType model) {
        Browser browser = null;
        switch (model) {
            case IE:
                browser = new IE();
                break;

            case SAFARI:
                browser = new Safari();
                break;

            case CHROME:
                browser = new Chrome();
                break;

            default:
                // throw some exception
                break;
        }
        return browser;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Then I didn't understand your question.